# What is this sign in Season 5, Episode 1?

Tags: the-walking-dead

At the end of the credits of *The Walking Dead* epsiode S05E01 we got to see a familiar face, seemingly following the group. He seems to be able to follow them from a "sign" carved into a tree? Or am I misreading this scene?

[image]

Comment: The weird thing is, the "No Sanctuary" sign seems to have aged and grown vines, making it appear as if that scene might be in the future?  And I didn't see anyone carving those X's, nor did I notice them when the group was walking through that area just after Rick put the mud on it.

Comment: Also, when re-watching the episode last night I noticed that there were multiple trees in this scene that have these marks. I don't see how anyone in the group would have time to carve out these marks in all those trees.

Comment: As shown in the episodes that follow, other trees also have markings carved into them. One in particular with a fairly large "dash" symbol. Further, remember that the man in the picture is Morgan Jones, the first man Rick meets after he wakes up in the hospital after the world became infested with walkers. In the season 3 episode, "Clear", they encounter Morgan in a booby-trapped town, and he's been writing, "Clear" on everything. I believe one of the marks he used to indicate "clear" status was an X, so this mark could be one he applied to the tree, to signify the area as "clear".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In episode 2, **Strangers**, just before Bob is abducted we see a gash carved into a tree. I presumed this was made by the gang from Terminus.

Then in the next episode, **Four Walls and a Roof**, the leader of the terminus gang, Gareth, is telling Bob why they did what they did. He says:

> You know, we marked our way here so that we could find our way back
>   after

So I thinks its' pretty clear the Terminus gang made the markings, which Morgan came across and followed to the church, where he can be seen at in the scene after the credits on episode 6.